# Type error in explicitly typed binding in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm a having a type error on my Haskell Code. `termEnVoc` is expected to return `True` if the `Term` given is part of the `Vocabulario` (vocabulary), I'm not completely sure if it works but anyway I can't understand why do I get a type error.

Here it's the code:

```
 type Cte = Simbolo
    type Funcion = (Simbolo,Aridad)
    type Predicado = (Simbolo, Aridad)
    type Vocabulario = ([Cte], [Funcion], [Predicado])

    data Term = C Simbolo | L Var | F Simbolo [Term]
        deriving (Show, Eq)

    termEnVoc :: Term -> Vocabulario -> Bool --This is line 38, the one with the error
    termEnVoc = \t -> \(cs,fs,ps)-> (or(map (\x ->(x==t))cs) || or(map (\x ->(x==t))f) || or(map (\x ->(x==t))p));
```

And here the error:

```
ERROR file:.\tarea3.hs:38 - Type error in explicitly typed binding
*** Term           : termEnVoc
*** Type           : [Char] -> ([[Char]],[([Char],Int)],[([Char],Int)]) -> Bool
*** Does not match : Term -> Vocabulario -> Bool
```

Comment: Try commenting out the type signature, then checking it's type interactively.  Also, I would very strongly recommend using GHC over Hugs.  The latest release of Hugs was 8 years ago, and it has far fewer features, more bugs, and is not even close to being as up to date with the Haskell standard than GHC.  If you install GHC, you can check the type of a function in scope in GHCi using the `:type` command, and you can load a file into the REPL using the `:load <filename.hs>` command.

Comment: @bheklilr I have really little knowledge of Haskell and I'm being teached with Hugs, anyway thanks for the advice I will take a look at GHC and see if I can work it out there.

Comment: Small tip: `or(map (\x ->(x==t))cs == any (==t) cs == elem t cs`

Comment: @moondaisy Grab the [Haskell platform installer](http://www.haskell.org/platform/), it's very easy to set up and comes with a lot of standard, popular libraries.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen thanks, I guess I will read the method of Data.List before doing more messy stuff.

Comment: What is the definition of `Simbolo` and `Aridad`?

Comment: `x==t` is comparing `Simbolo` and `Term`, which are different types. Maybe something like `C x == t` is what you want.

Comment: Note that GHCi is actually run using the `ghci` command. You should be able to do most things in GHCi that you can in hugs. As mentioned above, you will be able to get better answers if you include enough source code to figure out what the code in question means. `Simbolo`, `Aridad`, and `Cte` are completely mysterious.  I will, however, make an attempt at an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As chi suggests, the main problem appears to be that you are trying to compare `Term`s with values of other types. It's hard to see just what you're trying to do (specifically, what different types are supposed to represent), but here's the general way you probably want to structure the function definition:

```
termEnVoc (C simbolo) (cs, fs, ps) = cte `elem` cs
termEnVoc (F simbolo termList) (cs, fs, ps) = head $ filter ((== f) . fst) fs
termEnVoc (L var) (cs, fs, ps) = head $ filter ((== var) . fst) ps
```

As I indicated, some (or even most) of the details may be wrong, but this should give you a sense of how to structure the definition. The code above makes use of the following:

```
(== x)  =  (\y -> y == x)
```

You can actually do this with operators in general:

```
(/ 3) = (\x -> x/3)
```

and

```
(3 /) = (\x -> 3/x)
```

The only one that's wonky is subtraction, and I always have to look up the rules for that.

```
elem a as = or $ map (== a) as

a `elem` b = elem a b

filter p [] = []
filter p (x:xs)
  | p x        = x : filter p xs
  | otherwise  = filter p xs
```

Note that the real definitions of the above are likely different, for efficiency reasons.

Comment: Thanks I though that was probably the error, I was trying to do way too much stuff on one line.

Answer (score 0):

I finally decided that the problem was as dfeuer said that I was comparing terms with values of other types.
I end up with this method:

```
esTerm :: Vocabulario -> Term -> Bool
esTerm = \(c,f,p)-> \t -> case t of {
        C x -> elem x c;
        L x -> True;
        F n ts -> case (lookup n f) of {
            Nothing -> False;
            Just x -> x==(length ts)&& and(map (esTerm (c,f,p)) ts);
        }
}
```

Thanks for the help, it was really useful for fixing other mistakes I was making on my project.